# If current page is X, do this action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple site, which slides the content off the page before taking you to the URL. However, I need to be able to determine the slide direction, depending on which page you're currently on.

I need to do this, but I'm not sure how to articulate it properly with jQuery:

```
if (current page == about.php) {
   animate right then go to target URL }
else {
 do default behaviour }
```

At the moment, I have this function which doesn't work well, because it animates in a certain way regardless of which URL you're going to:

```
function animateLeftAndGo(x) {

        $(x).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = this.href;
        $('.pop-up').fadeOut(function(){
        $('.wrapper').animate({left: "+=150%"}, "slow", function(){
            window.location = href;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Which is called by:

```
animateLeftAndGo('a.archive');
```

How can I set up an `if statement` that asks if the current URL is `about.php`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In JavaScript use the location object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

if (location.pathname == '') {
}

Comment: No idea, link to w3schools? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: How can I say if `target location is`, too?